# Sockets: Android to Unity, possible allocation attack?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sockets, unity3d-mirror

I have a client app on Android using Java, and a server on my laptop in a Unity game. Both are on same network, and I got them to connect. When I send a small string message from client to server, though, the server blocks it with this warning:
`ReadMessageBlocking: possible allocation attack with a header of 1298494342 bytes.` How should I even *begin* approaching this roadblock?

For server, I'm using Unity's [Mirror](https://github.com/vis2k/Mirror/) library, that is built on top of the [Telepathy](https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/) framework.
For client, I followed the client part of [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2017/05/01/client-server-programming-in-android-send-message-to-the-client-and-back/) tutorial.

[This](https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/master/Telepathy/Common.cs) (from Telepathy) contains the relevant method (`ReadMessageBlocking`) that throws this warning. I tried setting the `MaxMessageSize` to `int.MaxValue` (which comes to 2 GB) to at least accept the message so I could inspect it by printing its contents, but no avail.

I don't have a problem with `ReadMessageBlocking`, it's there for good reason. My concern is: Why in the world is my android, allegedly, sending a 1 GB header with the string? What can I do about it?

Edit: This is the relevant function that sends message from client (as given in the tutorial mentioned earlier.)

```
void sendMessage(final String message) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (null != socket) {
                            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                                    true);
                            out.println(message);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    }
```

For (Unity) server to receive, I didn't write anything. The warning comes from Telepathy's internal message handling function, which I think is the [ReceiveLoop](https://github.com/vis2k/Telepathy/blob/master/Telepathy/Common.cs) here.

Comment: I think it would help if you show the code you are using for sending and receiving the message

Comment: There, I added all I could manage. Server receiver code is really long, and I don't think there's anything valuable in there, so linked. But I don't know. Hope it is sufficient.

Comment: This looks like the Android c++ code .. where is the Unity c# code?

Comment: I did mention that the client is "on Android using Java". It's an Android app I wrote. While, the server is on laptop, and *is* in Unity C#. It's a Unity game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Telepathy (and by extension, Mirror) uses a `byte[]` array to communicate packets, with the usual format of `<size,message>`. That means, the size (in bytes) of the message you want to send needs to be specified in the array first, followed by the bytes of the actual message content.

Since I'm using Java on the other side, `DataOutputStream` makes it a bit easier:

```
DataOutputStream d_out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
byte [] byte_message = message.getBytes();
d_out.writeInt(byte_message.length);
d_out.write(byte_message);
```

Since I wasn't using `DataOutputStream` earlier, Telepathy interpreted the full message content as `size` and crying. So the full working `Send` code now looks like this:

```
void sendMessage(final String message) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (null != socket) {
                            DataOutputStream d_out = new                             
                            DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                            byte [] byte_message = message.getBytes();
                            d_out.writeInt(byte_message.length);
                            d_out.write(byte_message);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending your packet with an incorrect header saying your packet is very large in the header, which the server then detects cause it wants to prevent overload from multiple packets with sent headers saying it is much larger than it is in reality.

Let the header be an appropiate size

> I tried setting the MaxMessageSize to int.MaxValue

Is too big

Comment: I set it to `int.MaxValue` on the _server side_, to at least have the server **accept** the message, instead of straightaway ditching it (since 2 GB > the 1 GB message header it is getting.) Otherwise, server throws the warning and discards the message at appropriate size.  I haven't touched the message, or its headers. I actually _do_ want to edit the packet header, but don't know how to, that is the question.

Comment: This suggests that the serverside was not changed if it is ditching appropiate sizes, I suggest some code that is sure to fail to be able to test if the serverside is changed

Comment: I suspect we're not on the same page. Allow me to elaborate. `MaxMessageSize` is a variable that exists on server code, to help decide the maximum size of messages (from client) that the server will accept. Every time the client sends a message, the server uses this variable to check if its size is below this size. By default, this variable is set to 16 kb. Now, for some mysterious reason, the client is sending a message with *1 GB* of header. Naturally, on seeing this, the server freaks out, since 1 GB is a *whole* lot bigger than its 16 kb default, and discards the message entirely.

Comment: Since the server just straight up discards, I couldn't inspect the contents of what it received. That's why, I tried to set the variable to max possible, hoping the message packet will lie in the size range, not get discarded, and let me at least inspect what the giant a** header is. Throughout all this, the packet (and its headers) I haven't touched.